# How to make it impossible for a postgres user to delete databases?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, configuration

What yould be the sql statement (that the user postgres will execute) so it will be impossible for the postgres user `user1` to delete (drop) databases?

Or can I add a rule into some config file?

Comment: Does `user1` own the database?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: at the present he does, but not necessarily, I could just change the ownership to postgres if necessary?

Comment: It would be best to have a solution for databases that `user1` owns, but I'd also behappy to have at least the other option.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think the owner can always drop the database. So you should make the user `postgres` the owner of the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, only the owner of a database can [drop a database](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-dropdatabase.html). (Superusers can drop databases, but that's a different issue.) So changing the owner is the most direct way to prevent user1 from dropping any databases.

Fix that with [ALTER DATABASE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdatabase.html).

```
ALTER DATABASE name OWNER TO new_owner
```

> To alter the owner, you must own the database and also be a direct or
>   indirect member of the new owning role, and you must have the CREATEDB
>   privilege. (Note that superusers have all these privileges
>   automatically.)

To give specific permissions back to user1, use [GRANT](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html).  You're probably looking for something like

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA schema_name TO user1;
```

But read the documentation for GRANT first. You might need WITH GRANT OPTION, permissions on sequences, something less than ALL PRIVILEGES, and so on.

Comment: But now user1 cant do anything with the database anymore. How can I allow user1 to do everything else with it (but not dropping)?

Comment: @mit: You probably need to grant the `CREATE` privilege on that database to the user.

Comment: Thank you, that really helps and saves me a lot of time, great!

Answer (score 0):

### Postgresql rules to stop a kind of event from happening on an object:

```
\dn                                        --shows your schema name 
SELECT session_user, current_user;         --shows your user 

--create a regular table with some data in it:
drop table if exists mytable; 
CREATE TABLE mytable( index integer, foo character varying(10)); 
insert into mytable values (3, 'yatta'); 
insert into mytable values (9, 'phobos'); 
select * from mytable; 
┌───────┬────────┐ 
│ index │  foo   │ 
├───────┼────────┤ 
│     3 │ yatta  │ 
│     9 │ phobos │ 
└───────┴────────┘ 
--Make a rule to stop deletes on a table:
CREATE or replace RULE mytable_del_protect AS ON DELETE TO mytable 
DO INSTEAD NOTHING; 

--Try to do a delete on the table
delete from mytable where index = 3;    --delete succeeds and affects 0 rows
select * from mytable;    --row you deleted is still there 
 
--Clear the rule: 
drop RULE mytable_del_protect on mytable; 
--once again try to delete
delete from mytable where index = 3;     --delete succeeds, affects 1 row
┌───────┬────────┐ 
│ index │  foo   │ 
├───────┼────────┤ 
│     9 │ phobos │ 
└───────┴────────┘
```

### List postgresql Rules:

Your rule information is encoded in `pg_rewrite` `pg_class` and `pg_namespace`:

```
select n.nspname as rule_schema, c.relname as rule_table, 
   case r.ev_type 
     when '1' then 'SELECT' 
     when '2' then 'UPDATE' 
     when '3' then 'INSERT' 
     when '4' then 'DELETE' 
     else 'UNKNOWN' 
   end as rule_event 
from pg_rewrite r join pg_class c on r.ev_class = c.oid 
  left join pg_namespace n on n.oid = c.relnamespace 
  where c.relname = 'mytable'

┌─────────────┬────────────┬────────────┐ 
│ rule_schema │ rule_table │ rule_event │ 
├─────────────┼────────────┼────────────┤ 
│ public      │ mytable    │ DELETE     │ 
└─────────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```

Instead of a Rule doing nothing on prevented delete, you could call a procedure.  You can create a rule to do anything, on any kind of event on any kind of database object.